# Visual Studio C# pictureBox - drawing in From constructor doesn't show up

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have the problem that I want to draw on a pictureBox with an image loaded before the user gets to see it. The drawing in principle works, but if I do it in the constructor it doesn't show up. It does work if I call the same function with a button.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        draw();

    }

    public void draw()
    {
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
        Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(new Point(20, 20), new Size(40, 40));
        rect.Offset(8, 8);
        g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Brushes.Black, 2), rect);
        g.Dispose();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        draw();
    }
```

I would have assumed that the circle would show up when the Form loads but it only does when I press the button. The code itself gets executed, as tested with a Message box.

Comment: You should use a Bitmap. `pictureBox1.Image = myBitmap;`

Comment: call method draw(); from form load event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control paints itself in its `Paint` event, so as soon as it's shown on screen (ie, after your code), it will paint itself in dull gray as normal.

If you want to custom paint a control, any control, you either override its `OnPaint` function or subscribe to its exposed `Paint` event.

A hint should be the fact that you had to create your own `Graphics` object, as opposed to using the object constructed during normal painting operations, that also includes proper clipping handling.

Comment: As to the button painting your control, try minimizing and restoring your window, and the "painting" should be gone -- again, because the control painted itself.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Still I'm wondering why my way didn't work. The loading of the PictureBox should be complete after InitializeComponent(); , or not?

Comment: As I said, every control paints itself when Winodws requests it to paint itself -- when you cover it on screen, when you minimize it or when it's shown (not loaded). Showing happens way after your constructor, there's a `Shown` event when the form is fully shown.